# Как реализовать правильно timeout на сокетах?

Tags: сокет, timeout

У мне в голове это выглядит так:

1. Проверяю функцией ioctlsocket((*this).sock, FIONREAD, &arg); наличие данных для считывания recv;
2. Если ничего нет, жду например 100 мс и опять проверяю.
3. Если так раз 5-10 ничего нет - значит сервер не ответил. В противном случае начинаю считывать данные.

Спрашиваю, потому что, если в клиент вызов recv сразу за send происходит быстро, и сервер не успевает обработать и послать обратно сообщение, значит клиенту нечего принять? Или я опять чего то не понял? :)

**Дополнено.**

Клиент:

- 1 секунда - клиент отправил данные
- 2 секунда клиент проверил буффер с помощью ioctlsocket , данных нет

Сервер:

- 1 секунда - сервер получил данные
- 2 секунда - сервер обрабатывает данные
- 3 секунда - сервер посылает данные

Я почему и спрашиваю, может быть такое или нет?

Comment: Поясните задачу. Сервер не может что-то не успеть, там буффер разный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте ф-ю `select`. В нее можно передать время ожидания на данные. Если появляются данные в сокете, она вернет управление. Иначе, по истечению заданного времени, вернется ошибка времени ожидания.

Comment: В виндовс есть эта функция?

Comment: Нашел уже на msdn. Спасибо.